# it might be very silly question , when I input a value between 1-7 it should print("User Mesage is "..... but it does to else and print help 2

Tags: python, if-statement

all works fine but when i enter a value between 1-7 it `prints("help 2")` instead of   `print("User Message is  + "'" + user_message + "'")` , please tell what to do i am stuck

```
m =  input('\n')

def cheakingIfMessageIsValicd():
    user_message = m
    user_message.lower()    
    try :
        user_message = int(user_message)
        if type(user_message) == int:
                if 0 < int(user_message) < 8:
                   print("User Message is  + "'" + user_message + "'") 
                else:
                    print("invalid row to place bolck")
    except:

        if user_message == "help":
            print("help")
        elif user_message == "start":
            print("start")
        else:
            print("help 2")

cheakingIfMessageIsValicd()
```

Comment: If ```user_message = int(user_message)``` is already there, why ```if type(user_message) == int```

Comment: Your `try` block is throwing an error, so it gets passed to except. You're then only checking if `user_message` is 'help' or 'start'. Anything else passes 'help 2'

Answer (score 2):

You should have kept the exception and printed it

```
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

It says `can only concatenate str (not "int") to str`, here's a better version

```
def cheakingIfMessageIsValicd():
    user_message = m
    user_message.lower()
    try:
        int_user_message = int(user_message)
        if 0 < int_user_message < 8:
            print("User Message is", "'" + user_message + "'")
        else:
            print("invalid row to place bolck")
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        if user_message == "help":
            print("help")
        elif user_message == "start":
            print("start")
        else:
            print("help 2")
```

Answer (score 2):

```
print("User Message is  + "'" + user_message + "'")
```

You didn't end the string! Also user_message is an integer, which can't be added to strings. This throws an error in the block which causes python to run the help 2 block.

This should work fine:

```
print("User Message is " + "'" + str(user_message) + "'")
```

Though I suggest you use a f-string:

```
print(f"User message is '{user_message}'"}
```

(At a basic level, f-strings allow you to easily insert variables into strings by using curly brackets)

Comment: I would not recommend ```f-strings``` to a beginner

Comment: Why not? The concept is very easy and they are simply awesome.

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 problems:

1. Bare `except`. This will suppress all your exceptions, regardless of what they mean, their importance, etc.
2. You cannot concatenate strings and integer. Instead, you should use a `,`, or `f-strings`: `f"{}"`, or convert the integer to a string

```
m =  input('\n')

def cheakingIfMessageIsValicd():
    user_message = m
    user_message.lower()    
    try:
        user_message = int(user_message)
        if type(user_message) == int:
                if 0 < int(user_message) < 8:
                    print("User Message is" + "'" + str(user_message) + "'")
                else:
                    print("invalid row to place bolck")
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        if user_message == "help":
            print("help")
        elif user_message == "start":
            print("start")
        else:
            print("help 2")

cheakingIfMessageIsValicd()
```

Answer (score 0):

## Actual Problems Occurring in Code  -

1. Unbalanced Double Quotes
   Consequence - Whole Program logic deteriorates, and interpreter can't understand the code
2. Concatenation operator (+) forced to concatenate values of unmatched data type - (In your case) Strings and 'user_message' variable
   Consequence - Exception Raised
3. Unsafe except - This is not in the actual Problem list for your code, but as a brother's tip, I suggest use Exception keyword too.
   Reason - It saves the code from running indefinitely in case of any abrupt looping, by allowing you to stop the code with an interrupt like keyboard interrupt

## Fixes

1. You can easily switch usage between single-quotes(') and double quotes("), as in Python, both of them mean the same.
2. As suggested by others too, use the powerful python feature, namely f-strings, this not only saves you from various other-data-type-to-string-conversions, but also increases readability of you code.
3. Use -  except Exception as E: ..... even though you don't need the error message E.
   Use this generally in almost all of your future codes

## Optimal and Suggested Improvements

1. Use range() data type wherever needed
2. Use 'in' operator
3. Use parameter passing to make your methods(functions) versatile
4. Use if **name** == '**main**': to make your code Reusable/importable for other Programs

## Final code with all of the mentioned Improvements...

```
def CheakingIfMessageIsValid(user_message):
    try :
        if int(user_message) in range(8):
            print(f"User Message is '{user_message}'") 
        else:
            print("invalid row to place block")

    except Exception as E:
        user_message = user_message.lower()
        if user_message in ["help", "start"]:
            print(user_message)
        else:
            print("help 2")


if __name__ == '__main__': 
    data = input('\n')
    CheakingIfMessageIsValid(data)
```

Comment: Hope the tips help you! saksham